# OUTER JOIN not returning expected results in EF Core

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core, outer-join

In my ASP.NET MVC Core app the `POST` action method `Test` is not returning the expected results. The web app was created using [this official ASP.NET Core site](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html) and was modified slightly. The real app can be [downloaded from here](https://github.com/saf-itpro/ASP_Core_Blogs_GitHub) and is using latest version of `VS2015`. The app is using `EF Core`.
If you download the project, you will need to do the following steps to test the above unexpected results:

**Note**:  Order of these steps is important. This is a very small test project. Step2 will create a small SQL Server Db called ASPCore_Blogs. So make sure SQL Server is runing:

1. After you download the project, make sure you delete the `.vs` folder from the project directory before opening the project in VS2015 (if project hangs, you may have to force close it using `Task Manager` of windows os and re-open it to make it work. This is a known issue in VS2015).
2. Open `startup.cs` file and in the Configuration() method change the database instance name from `MyComputer\SQLServerInstance` to whatever instance you are using. Do the same in the `appsettings.json` file in the root directory.
3. In VS2015 PM window, run PM> update-database -context BloggingContext [Make sure SQL Server is running]
4. Then run: PM> update-database -context ApplicationDbContext
5. Run the web app. Register by entering a login/password info. login need to be in an Email (test@test.com) form. On the left side of Home page:
6. Click on the link `Blog Create` to create 4 blogs as: Blog1@test.com, Blog2@test.com, Blog3@test.com, Blog4@test.com
7. Click on the link `Blogs Index` to verify all the above 4 blogs were created
8. Click on the `Test` link. This view is called by the `GET` action method `Test`. On the corrsponding view (`Test.cshtml`) you will see `Url` column on the page is showing all 4 above blogs. And `Title` and `Content` columns are blanks. Fill the `Title` column as: Title1, Title2, Title3, Title4. Fill the `Content` column as: Content1 ,Content2 ,Content3 ,Content4
9. Now, go to the corresponding SQL Server DB called `ASPCore_BlogsNAxis` and open `Posts` table in `Edit` mode to manually change the PostYear column values to: 1998,1999,1998,2001 respectively (note: 1998 is repeated on purpose)
10. Now, go to `Blogs` table in the same SQL Server DB and enter an extra blog `Blog5@test.com`
11. Now, run the web app and click on `Test` link (on the left side of the Home page) again. You'll see that the `Get` action method `Test` is using left outer join to display all 5 blogs but the right side columns (`Title` and `Content`) values are blanks in the 5th row, as expected, since left outer join does not satisfy the join condition on `BlogId` for the 5th blog. So far so good.
12. Now, on the `Year` dropdown on the `Test.cshtml` view, select year as 1998 and click on `GO` button. According to the first `if` condition of the `POST` action method `Test` the app should display only three records (two for 1998 and the 5th one that does not satisfy join condition): first, 3rd, and 5th record.

But that's not what happening. When you repeat this action by selecting various years years from the dropdown and click `GO`button, you'll see the output is not as expected.

**Example Data**:

*Blogs Table Data*:

```
BlogId  Url
1       test1.com
2       test2.com
3       test3.com
4       test4.com
5       test5.com
```

*Posts Table Data*:

```
PostId  BlogId  Content  PostYear  Title
  1       1     Content1    1998    Title1
  2       2     Content2    1999    Title2
  3       3     Content3    1998    Title3
  4       4     Content4    2001    Title4
```

*LEFT Outer JOIN in `Test` Action GET Method Should return*:

```
BlogId  Url PostId  Content PostYear    Title
1   test1.com   1   Content1    1998    Title1
2   test2.com   2   Content2    1999    Title2
3   test3.com   3   Content3    1998    Title3
4   test4.com   4   Content4    2001    Title4
5   test5.com   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

*And when you select year 1998 in the dropdown and click on Go button, the Test(...) Post action method query should return*. **But it's randomly returning any rows**:

```
BlogId  Url        PostId  Content    PostYear  Title
  1     test1.com     1     Content1    1998    Title1
  3     test3com      3     Content2    1998    Title3
  5     test5.com     NULL  NULL        NULL    NULL
```

**Models**:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostYear { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

**BlogsController**:

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public BlogsController(BloggingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: Blogs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Blogs.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /Blogs/Test
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.YearsList = Enumerable.Range(1996, 29).Select(g => new SelectListItem { Value = g.ToString(), Text = g.ToString() }).ToList();

        //return View(await _context.Blogs.Include(p => p.Posts).ToListAsync());
        var qrVM = from b in _context.Blogs
                    join p in _context.Posts on b.BlogId equals p.BlogId into bp
                    from c in bp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel { BlogID = b.BlogId, PostID = (c == null ? 0 : c.PostId), Url = b.Url, Title = (c == null ? string.Empty : c.Title), Content = (c == null ? string.Empty : c.Content) };
        return View(await qrVM.ToListAsync());
    }

    // POST: /Blogs/Test
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(List<BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel> list, string GO, int currentlySelectedIndex, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.YearsList = Enumerable.Range(1996, 29).Select(g => new SelectListItem { Value = g.ToString(), Text = g.ToString() }).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GO))
        {
            var qrVM = from b in _context.Blogs
                        join p in _context.Posts on b.BlogId equals p.BlogId into bp
                        from c in bp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where c == null? true : c.PostYear.Equals(currentlySelectedIndex)
                        select new BlogsWithRelatedPostsViewModel { BlogID = b.BlogId, PostID = (c == null ? 0 : c.PostId), Url = b.Url, Title = (c == null ? string.Empty : c.Title), Content = (c == null ? string.Empty : c.Content) };
            return View(await qrVM.ToListAsync());
        }
        else if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var oPost = _context.Posts.Where(r => r.PostId.Equals(item.PostID)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (oPost != null)
                {
                    oPost.Title = item.Title;
                    oPost.Content = item.Content;
                    oPost.PostYear = currentlySelectedIndex;
                    oPost.BlogId = item.BlogID; //according to new post below the blogId should exist for a newly created port - but just in case
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.PostID == 0)
                    {
                        Post oPostNew = new Post { BlogId = item.BlogID, Title = item.Title, Content = item.Content, PostYear = currentlySelectedIndex }; //need to use currentlySelectedIndex intead of item.FiscalYear in case of adding a record
                        _context.Add(oPostNew);
                    }

                }
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            return View(list);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Blogs/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var blog = await _context.Blogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BlogId == id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(blog);
    }

    // GET: Blogs/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Blogs/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("BlogId,Url")] Blog blog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Blogs.Add(blog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    // GET: Blogs/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var blog = await _context.Blogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BlogId == id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    // POST: Blogs/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("BlogId,Url")] Blog blog)
    {
        if (id != blog.BlogId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(blog);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BlogExists(blog.BlogId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    // GET: Blogs/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var blog = await _context.Blogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BlogId == id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(blog);
    }

    // POST: Blogs/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var blog = await _context.Blogs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BlogId == id);
        _context.Blogs.Remove(blog);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private bool BlogExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Blogs.Any(e => e.BlogId == id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

1. Added step 2 asking users to change the connection string
2. Removed new Post() from the bp.DefaultIfEmpty(new Post()) in the GET/POST action methods of `Test()`. But the same error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

in the linq query, where you do the `DefaultIfEmtpy` call:

```
from c in bp.DefaultIfEmpty(new Post())
where c == null? true : c.PostYear.Equals(currentlySelectedIndex)
```

you used the overload where `DefaultIfEmtpy` will return the `new Post()` instance when it is empty, instead of returning null. But then your logic expects it to return `null`. replace the first line of the snipper with the overload that returns `null` instead:

```
from c in bp.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. `new Post()` was added after I was getting unexpected results. But the same unexpected behavior is still there. Anyhow, I've removed removed `new Post()` and added an **UPDATE** section to my post.